# phpmyadmin installed successfully but doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, command-line, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I've installed phpmyadmin on ubuntu 14.04 successfully but I cannot access the interface. I mean `http://mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin` is this:

[image]

Why it isn’t working and how can I fix the problem?

Noted that I installed phpmyadmin by following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: @stack, what is your web server? I suppose it is Apache and you have missed to select that option in to the beginning of the installation.

Comment: @pa4080 Yes it is appache .. and I suspect about security part, I mean I guess something went wrong there. Because I seen the interface as well when I hadn't done security part yet.

Comment: Does the address `http://mywebsite.com` is accesible or you receive the same error message?

Comment: @pa4080 [it is availible](http://lamtakam.com/)

Comment: If you remove the file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess` and restart Apache, could you access the phpMyAdmin interface?

Comment: @pa4080 sadly no .. can you please take a look at my server if I give you user and password?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70486/discussion-between-pa4080-and-stack).